# Mounting /dev/shm in a Gentoo chroot on Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, gentoo, chroot

I'm trying to install Gentoo, and instead of using one of the bootable minimal install CDs provided by Gentoo, I'm using a chroot in Ubuntu. I'm mainly following the instructions outlined here, http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Gentoo-Linux-from-Ubuntu but I'm also turning to this guide whenever I need. https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64

Now, I've decided to bootstrap my installation for optimal performance, and after some initial hiccups, I've gotten to the point where I'm supposed to run "emerge -e system". Whenever I do this, it fails with these errors:

```
 * configure has detected that the sem_open function is broken.
 * Please ensure that /dev/shm is mounted as a tmpfs with mode 1777.
 * ERROR: dev-lang/python-2.7.7::gentoo failed (configure phase):
 *   Broken sem_open function (bug 496328)
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line  93:  Called src_configure
 *   environment, line 3892:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *           die "Broken sem_open function (bug 496328)";
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-lang/python-2.7.7::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-lang/python-2.7.7::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.7/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.7/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.7/work/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.7/work/Python-2.7.7'

>>> Failed to emerge dev-lang/python-2.7.7, Log file:

>>>  '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.7/temp/build.log'

 * Messages for package sys-apps/sysvinit-2.88-r7:

 * The last/lastb/mesg/mountpoint/sulogin/utmpdump/wall tools have been moved to
 * sys-apps/util-linux. The pidof tool has been moved to sys-process/procps.

 * Messages for package dev-libs/glib-2.40.0-r1:

 * Unable to find kernel sources at /usr/src/linux
 * Unable to calculate Linux Kernel version for build, attempting to use running version

 * Messages for package dev-lang/python-2.7.7:

 * configure has detected that the sem_open function is broken.
 * Please ensure that /dev/shm is mounted as a tmpfs with mode 1777.
 * ERROR: dev-lang/python-2.7.7::gentoo failed (configure phase):
 *   Broken sem_open function (bug 496328)
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line  93:  Called src_configure
 *   environment, line 3892:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *           die "Broken sem_open function (bug 496328)";
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-lang/python-2.7.7::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-lang/python-2.7.7::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.7/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.7/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.7/work/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.7/work/Python-2.7.7'
```

Here is the output from emerge --info '=dev-lang/python-2.7.7::gentoo' :

```
    Portage 2.2.14 (python 2.7.7-final-0, default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop, gcc-4.8.3, glibc-2.19-r1, 3.17.2-zen-liquorix-**************-**** x86_64)
=================================================================
                         System Settings
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-3.17.2-zen-liquorix-**************-****-x86_64-Intel-R-_Core-TM-2_Duo_CPU_E8500_@_3.16GHz-with-gentoo-2.2
KiB Mem:     8180452 total,   5912720 free
KiB Swap:    8386556 total,   8386556 free
Timestamp of tree: Sat, 13 Dec 2014 21:30:01 +0000
ld GNU ld (Gentoo 2.24 p1.4) 2.24
app-shells/bash:          4.2_p45
dev-lang/perl:            5.18.2-r1
dev-lang/python:          2.7.7, 3.3.5-r1
dev-util/pkgconfig:       0.28-r1
sys-apps/baselayout:      2.2
sys-apps/openrc:          0.12.4
sys-apps/sandbox:         2.6-r1
sys-devel/autoconf:       2.69
sys-devel/automake:       1.13.4
sys-devel/binutils:       2.24-r3
sys-devel/gcc:            4.8.3
sys-devel/gcc-config:     1.7.3
sys-devel/libtool:        2.4.2-r1
sys-devel/make:           3.82-r4
sys-kernel/linux-headers: 3.16 (virtual/os-headers)
sys-libs/glibc:           2.19-r1
Repositories: gentoo
ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="* -@EULA"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-march=core2 -msse4.1 -O2 -pipe"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/env.d /etc/gconf /etc/gentoo-release /etc/sandbox.d /etc/terminfo"
CXXFLAGS="-march=core2 -msse4.1 -O2 -pipe"
DISTDIR="/usr/portage/distfiles"
FCFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-logs config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles merge-sync news parallel-fetch preserve-libs protect-owned sandbox sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch userpriv usersandbox usersync"
FFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
GENTOO_MIRRORS="http://gentoo.arcticnetwork.ca/ http://gentoo.gossamerhost.com/ rsync://gentoo.gossamerhost.com/gentoo-distfiles/ http://mirror.the-best-hosting.net/ ftp://mirrors.tera-byte.com/pub/gentoo http://gentoo.mirrors.tera-byte.com/ rsync://mirrors.tera-byte.com/gentoo ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/gentoo-distfiles/ http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/gentoo-distfiles/"
LANG="en_US.utf8"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
MAKEOPTS="-j3"
PKGDIR="/usr/portage/packages"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --omit-dir-times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp"
PORTDIR="/usr/portage"
PORTDIR_OVERLAY=""
USE="X a52 aac acl acpi alsa amd64 berkdb bindist bluetooth branding bzip2 cairo cdda cdr cli consolekit cracklib crypt cups cxx dbus dri dts dvd dvdr emboss encode exif fam firefox flac fortran gdbm gif glamor gpm gtk iconv ipv6 jpeg lcms ldap libnotify mad mmx mng modules mp3 mp4 mpeg multilib ncurses nls nptl ogg opengl openmp pam pango pcre pdf png policykit ppds qt3support qt4 readline sdl session spell sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 ssl ssse3 startup-notification svg tcpd tiff truetype udev udisks unicode upower usb vorbis wxwidgets x264 xcb xml xv xvid zlib" ABI_X86="64" ALSA_CARDS="ali5451 als4000 atiixp atiixp-modem bt87x ca0106 cmipci emu10k1x ens1370 ens1371 es1938 es1968 fm801 hda-intel intel8x0 intel8x0m maestro3 trident usb-audio via82xx via82xx-modem ymfpci" APACHE2_MODULES="authn_core authz_core socache_shmcb unixd actions alias auth_basic authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="kexi words flow plan sheets stage tables krita karbon braindump author" CAMERAS="ptp2" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ublox ubx" INPUT_DEVICES="keyboard mouse evdev" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LIBREOFFICE_EXTENSIONS="presenter-console presenter-minimizer" OFFICE_IMPLEMENTATION="libreoffice" PHP_TARGETS="php5-5" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python2_7" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_3" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby19 ruby20" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="fbdev glint intel mach64 mga nouveau nv r128 radeon savage sis tdfx trident vesa via vmware dummy v4l" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS, INSTALL_MASK, LC_ALL, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS, SYNC, USE_PYTHON

=================================================================
                        Package Settings
=================================================================

dev-lang/python-2.7.7 was built with the following:
USE="gdbm ipv6 ncurses readline ssl threads (wide-unicode) xml -berkdb -build -doc -examples -hardened -sqlite -tk -wininst" ABI_X86="64"
CFLAGS="-O2 -pipe -fwrapv"
CXXFLAGS="-O2 -pipe -fwrapv"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed -L."
```

For my chroot environment, I use the following mount commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/gentoo
sudo mount -t proc none /mnt/gentoo/proc
sudo mount --rbind /sys /mnt/gentoo/sys
sudo mount --rbind /dev /mnt/gentoo/dev
```

Even though I've figured out how to compile my own kernel in Ubuntu, I'm still a major Linux newbie. In fact, I only learned about /dev/shm yesterday. I also learned that on Ubuntu, /dev/shm is simply a link to /run/shm, so that's probably where my difficulties are coming from. I've actually tried mounting /run/shm as well, but it's to no avail.

If anyone knows how I could properly mount /dev/shm, that would be awesome.

Comment: I believe I may have already solved this myself. In the chroot I ran "mkdir /run/shm", then I exited the chroot and ran "sudo mount --rbind /run/shm /mnt/gentoo/run/shm". When I re-entered the chroot and ran "emerge -e system", it started to work! It's still in the middle of compiling, so I can't say if it was completely successful, but so far it looks good.

I can thank this Gentoo Forums thread for the idea: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-982100.html?sid=824c69b575a516218219e13fd4e44ffa

Comment: Does't Gentoo have an easier & faster way to install itself? (this reminds me of a bag full of floppies and running commands all day...)

Answer (score 4):

From the parent env, `mount --bind /dev/shm /mnt/gentoo/dev/shm`

Or here's the invocation that we use for Gentoo Infra:

```
echo /dev /dev/shm /dev/pts /proc /sys /run |xargs -n1 |xargs -I{} mount -o bind {} /mnt/gentoo/{}
```